# How can I hide some images (saved on the sdcard by my app) from the Gallery app in Android?

Tags: android, file, sd-card

My app is saving some images on the SD Card, in the AppImages directory

The inbuilt gallery app is detecting these images and showing them on the gallery.

It is possible to hide these images and to be visible only for my app?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename the directory from `AppImages` to `.AppImages`. The dot "hides" this folder from the system.

On an unrelated note, consider naming the folder something less generic to lessen the chance that it already exists.

Comment: This method will also stop several file managers, both on the phone and on the computer from showing the folder. This can be counter productive if the user wants to copy the files via USB, since he/she may not be able to see the folder.

Comment: @RaghavSood the files/folders will not be hidden when accessing the device over USB. The device file managers will most likely not find them though.

Comment: A lot of linux and windows file managers automatically hide folders and files beginning with a period. Granted it can be disabled in the settings (by checking the "Show Hidden Files and Folders" option in Windows explorer for example), but most users are unlikely to have done that.

Comment: @RaghavSood I suppose you are right, I always show hidden files so it is never really a problem for me :) Anyway, the question is to "hide these images and to be visible only for my app" so I suppose my answer still stands.

Comment: It still stands. It achieves what the OP wanted. I was just pointing out a perhaps unintended side effect.

Answer (score 2):

You could stop the gallery from picking up your apps photos by putting a `.nomedia` file in the folder where they are stored. This will stop the gallery app from detecting your images, but a user still can open them in the gallery by using a file manager to navigate to the directory and selecting an image.

Hiding the images from both the user and the gallery is not possible, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

No Need to hide the Picture.. just Rename the Extension like ".txt" it will show the pic like unsupported file